# Background video out of position in Safari only

Tags: html, css, video, safari, position

Background video out of position in Safari only. When I remove "top: 50%" and "left: 50%" it works on Safari but position then becomes out of place in Chrome, etc. Anyone got any ideas on how to get it working on both?

```
video { 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background: url(../images/vidstill.png) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

Comment: please add your html (important parts)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. For Safari to recognize the "transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);" you need to add another line: "-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);"

Adding the "-webkit" will help Safari understand what you want.  So it will end up looking like this:

```
video { 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background: url(../images/vidstill.png) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
transition: 1s opacity;
}
```